# C# Rich GUI Application

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, silverlight, user-interface

I want to create an app to declare microprocessor's pin as input/output with mouse clicks. I created a mockup - https://i.stack.imgur.com/GOHQ5.png. I think it would be best to declare each pin as an separate class so I can change its state easily, but I dont know how to achieve that along with graphical representation of it. Each square should be clickable and changin its color. Then foreach loop to iterate throu them and get state information of each.Should I go with WPF or Silverlight or just simple click events? What is the best approach to implement that in .NET?

Comment: Thank you all for suggestions. Will come back here later with something for sure. I think I will go with the MVVM pattern, seems reasonable.

Answer (score 1):

If you want a website, do Silverlight. Otherwise do WPF because it will be easier.

I'd just do an image for the center piece, unless it's going to change size, in which case you could just draw it out of lines and an ellipse. Use a Canvas in your main window, not a grid. Make a Pin class that handles the state/color/positioning information. You can draw the square with a Rectangle.

Don't worry about MVVM, that's going to be more trouble than it's worth for your case.

Answer (score 0):

Silverlight or WPF doesn't make much of a difference in this case. Deployment of the application (web or not) might help you chose.

Implement the state machine/processor as a class (ViewModel) and implement the UI as a View. That will help to keep the code clean. Look up MVVM Model-View-ViewModel.

Answer (score 0):

You could do this in WPF, Silverlight or Winforms.

From a graphical perspective, it might be easier to reproduce your mockup in WPF or Silverlight. Choosing between WPF and Silverlight really comes down to how you want to deploy the app (eg for SL you need a web server).

Make your choice, start writing code and then come back here with specific issues as you encounter them.

Good Luck.